# Display: flex on both parent and child element in navbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

Ok, here's the code for making web responsive navbar using flexbox. My question comes out of pure curiosity since I'm a newbie and just learning html&css and would like to understand the logic behind it:

Why is it necessary to give *display: flex* both to .navbar and its child .navbar ul class?
To display flex, we need to add it to a parent element, in this case it's nav.
Why won't it work like that, why is it necessary to add *display: flex* to its direct child .navbar ul as well? Thanks!

```
<nav class="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

 .navbar {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
position: sticky;
top: 0;
border: 3px dotted red;
}

.navbar ul {
display: flex;
margin: 20px 0px;
border: 3px dotted blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.navbar` centers  the `ul` (i.e. the links) in this case, due to its flex settings (horizontally *and* vertically).

On the `ul` the flex setting here only makes sure the `li`s are arranged horizontally - not necessarily a typical flex example.

I would add some details, especially padding or margins on the list items (see below) and `list-style-type: none;` on the `ul` to hide the default dots before the `li`s.

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 3px dotted red;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  border: 3px dotted blue;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar li {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer my question and explain it a bit more thoroughly. 
Basically an element can be both a flex parent/container and flex item at the same time. 
Which is exactly what happened in my example, because like you said, we needed to further arrange li items inside of ul container.

Now it's a bit more clear to me, thank you again!